# How to merge 2 queries results into one using Wordpress hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, search, hook, advanced-custom-fields

I am pretty new to Wordpress and recently I found this problem which took me a lot of time to understand but I can't still figure out how to resolve it.
I am using the **Wordpress basic search** using the classic **search.php**.
I need to retrieve **POSTS** based on their **post_title** *OR* their **custom field taxonomy**, for example my case taxonomy is '**color**', with **ACF** I added a new field called **synonimes** which is repeater field with inside N* text fields called **synonim**.
Basically I need to retrieve both posts with **synonimes** matching and **post_title** matching *(basically the classic 's' => $value inside wordpress query args)*, using the hook **pre_get_posts** I only reached the point where I can filter the **POSTS** with a *AND* condition which is really wrong.
I don't know how to change this behavior and I gave up this way, I am now trying to merge the results I found with the primary Query in the hook.
I am now with this code here:

```
function filter_tax($query){
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search()) {

    $args_new_query = array(
        'post_type' => MAIN_POST,
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'post_parent' => 0,
    );

    $new_query = new WP_Query($args_new_query);

    $search_keyword = sanitize_text_field(get_search_query());

    $matching_posts = array();

    if ($new_query->have_posts()) {
        $taxonomy_name = 'color';

        while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $taxonomy_name);

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $synonim_values = get_field('synonimes', $taxonomy_name . '_' . $term->term_id);

                if (is_array($synonim_values)) {

                    foreach ($synonim_values as $syn) {
                        if (strpos($syn['synonim'], $search_keyword) !== false) {
                            $matching_posts[] = get_post($post_id);
                            break 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    if (!empty($matching_posts)) {
        /*$query->set('post__in', wp_list_pluck($matching_posts, 'ID'));*/
        $query->posts = array_merge([], $matching_posts);
    }
}
}
```

Unfortunately in my template I only can paginate basic search POSTS and my $**matching_posts** are lost and cannot be retrieved, It looks really simple but still it's taking me a lot of time.

Comment: Getting pagination to work properly, when you are appending to the data set yourself, is going to be tricky. You'd probably be better off with an approach as outlined here, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/224086 - `$query->query_vars['s']` gets set to an empty string, so that it does not get added to the query as it normally would; and then the query gets manipulated using the `posts_where` hook, to add the post title search in again with `OR`.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, this is how i modified the code
`if (!empty($matching_posts)) { $query->set('post__in', wp_list_pluck($matching_posts, 'ID')); $query->set('s', ''); /* $query->posts = array_merge([], $matching_posts);*/ /* add_filter('posts_search', "modify_search", 10, 2);*/ }
function modify_search($search, $query)
{
 if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search()) {
  $original_search = $query->query_vars['s'];
  $search .= " OR (post_title LIKE '%$original_search%')";
  echo '<br>';
  var_dump($search);
  echo '<br>';

  return $search;
 }
}` still doesn't work

Comment: If you're starting with `if (!empty($matching_posts))`, that must mean you are still doing your _own_ query first - which is contrary to what I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an error by misunderstanding the inner functionality of **POST__IN**.
Initially I thought i could *inject* **POSTS** by their **ID**, but this is wrong because I was filtering **POSTS** by their **ID**.
So I came up with this:

```
$args_basic = [
        'post_type' => $contentList,
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_parent' => 0,
        's' => $_GET['s'],
    ];

    $prev_search = get_posts($args_basic);
    $prev_search_ids = array_map(fn($item) => $item->ID, $prev_search);
    $query->set('post_type', $contentList);

    if (!empty($matching_posts)) {
        $ids_serach = array_merge($prev_search_ids, wp_list_pluck($matching_posts, 'ID'));
        $query->set('post__in', $ids_serach);
        $query->set('s', '');
    }
```

This is the correct way to use **POST__IN**.
I am leaving here my question and answer in case you are in the same boat, **don't waste time merging queryposts!**, **it will never work**.